# Spring -Hibernate - Struts Error 500 -- No action instance for path /customer could be created

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts

I had set up a struts form and spring-hibernate project.
I tried to access the jsp page that lists the items in the database. local:8989/JEE/customer.do
But it gives me error 500 instead : No action instance for path /customer could be created

Here is the log 4j : http://pastebin.com/4RZCSnhW

And this is the bean.xml that is used by the spring factory: pbin/9bkChQi2

I hv my Customer.hbm.xml : pbin/X8GTnP7M
I have checked it over and over again and find no errors in the > of the file.

Can someone pin point on what's the error ?

Thanks a lot for any of the helps.

Comment: But your SAX reader says the opposite thing. Also note that Hibernate has support for annotations.

Answer (score 0):

The error - as expected - is pointed to in the exception:

```
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 8 of document  : Element type "id" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". Nested exception: Element type "id" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:532)
```

One of your Hibernate mapping configuration files contains invalid XML.

Comment: I added hibernate plugin to eclipse and caught the errors. But I need to switch to Galileo from Indigo to get it.